# Why are inline code spans across multiple lines allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, code-formatting, markdown

From time to time, I see some code formatted using inline code spans like this:

`<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>I don't know how to format code properly</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>I'm not able to make my code look properly.</p>
    <p>Can someone help me? Thanks.</p>
</body>
</html>`

As far as I'm aware, there is no valid reason why one should have line breaks inside inline code spans. If your code is more than one line long or not within a sentence, it should be inside code blocks (indent all lines with four spaces):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>How to format code properly</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>You can format your code by indenting all lines of your code with four spaces.</p>
    <p>Select all your code, then click the {} button above the text box.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any reason why this is allowed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "allowed"?

Comment: @SantaClaus I am guessing that "allowed" means that it is not rejected by the software when a newline is contained within a set of backticks.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Or maybe it means not fixed (edited) by the community?

Comment: @SantaClaus Sorry, I should have made it more clear. The system should warn the user, just like how it warns when you don't format code at all (for new users).

Comment: Better yet, the system couldn't just warn the user, it could fix their formatting.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use multi-line inline code spans for code. Still, there is a valid use for them: Formatting error messages, which may get more line-breaks, but must keep their original linebreaks and should not be interpreted as formatting...

Comment: @Deduplicator That's better done using normal code blocks or code fences, it doesn't have to be single backticks.

Comment: This isn't just a problem for multi-line code blocks. If single backticks surround a single line of code it also looks bad compared to putting it in a real code block.

Answer (score 5):

While I don't know the direct "answer" to your question, given Santa's suggestion -- I rather like the idea that if you can be told you are incorrect by a computer, the computer should be able to fix it -- I decided to take a look at the compressed code.

In wmd.en.js

```
i=i.replace(/:\/\//g,"~P"),t+"<code>"+i+"</code>"
```

could be replaced with

```
i=i.replace(/:\/\//g,"~P"),t+i.indexOf("\n")>-1?i.replace(/^/gm, "    "):"<code>"+i+"</code>"
```

and I believe that will auto-"block" backticked multi-line code segments.

Seems like a rather minor change which would be of benefit.

**EDIT: Modifications based off the uncompressed version**

After seeing the uncompressed code, the code above is insufficient. It appears that the changes are in regards to these 2 lines in the `_DoCodeSpans` function:

```
c = c.replace(/:\/\//g, "~P"); // to prevent auto-linking. Not necessary in code *blocks*, but in code spans. Will be converted back after the auto-linker runs.
return m1 + "<code>" + c + "</code>";
```

Borrowing from the selection parsing routine and considering that `_DoCodeBlocks` is parsed before `_DoCodeSpans`, those 2 lines will need to be modified to

```
if (/\n/.test(c)) { // code span contains newline, so convert to code block
  return m1 + _DoCodeBlocks(c.replace(/^/gm, "    "));
} else {
  c = c.replace(/:\/\//g, "~P"); // to prevent auto-linking. Not necessary in code *blocks*, but in code spans. Will be converted back after the auto-linker runs.
  return m1 + "<code>" + c + "</code>";
}
```

Comment: No need to try and decipher the minified file! Just go to http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/wmd.en.js